# How to drop row in dataframe if I want to get average but there are no data points from before

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with more than 4000 rows and I am calculating averages from row 1179 in another dataframe based on that original dataframe. If value count for away team or home team is under 3 until that match in for loop, then I would like to drop row in second dataframe.

Dataframe example:

```
    Date       Match ID  Home team     Away team   Home score Away score 
1 2016/11/11         2   Penn St.      Wright St.    29       30          
2 2016/11/11         3  Southern Ill.  N.C. Central  33       34         
3 2016/11/11         4  East Carolina  Wichita St.   42       21          
4 2016/11/11         5  Longwood       Colgate       32       42         
5 2016/11/11         6  Lipscomb       Boston U.     21       21
```

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df1 = df.iloc[1179:]
matches = []
for a in df1['Match ID']:
    matches.append(a)

for match in matches:
    match_line = df1.loc[df1['Match ID'] == match]
    idx = df.index.get_loc(df[df['Match ID'] == match].index[0])
    print(idx)

    neki1 = df.iloc[:idx]
    home_team = match_line['Home team'].values[0]
    away_team = match_line['Away team'].values[0]
    home = neki1[neki1['Home team'] == home_team]
    home1 = neki1[neki1['Away team'] == home_team]
    away = neki1[neki1['Home team'] == away_team]
    away1 = neki1[neki1['Away team'] == away_team]

    home_score = []
    away_score = []
    for data in home['Home score']:
        home_score.append(data)
    for data in home1['Away score']:
        away_score.append(data)

    df1.loc[df1['Match ID'] == match, 'Home score'] = mean(home_score)
    df1.loc[df1['Match ID'] == match, 'Away score'] = mean(away_score)
```

I tried with value_counts but I don't get the correct results because it's not placed properly, so I just want to know the logic of where to place that.
I hope I was clear :)

Comment: Can you maybe share the dataframe? At least a few rows of the appropriate columns

Comment: just added to original post

Comment: Could you share the data *as text*, so that it can be copied easily. Also, do you realy mean "value_count" or rather just the value in the column? Ideally give also an example of output

Comment: output would be average score without scores reached with teams that played less than 3 games. So for example team A scores 50, 50, 50, 50, 80 points but last game was against a team that played only 2 games so far, the average should be 50 and not 56, so ideally I would drop that row to not count it for mean

Comment: Changed from image to text

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you want at each game the average of previous scores:

- for that team
- with same side (home or away)
- starting at row 1179
- averages over at least 3 games

The concept is called an [expanding transformation](https://devdocs.io/pandas%7E1/reference/api/pandas.dataframe.expanding), with the transformation here being the average (or `mean`).

This should work, roughly:

```
df1 = df.iloc[1179:]
df1['Home score'] = df.groupby(['Home team'])['Home score']\
                      .transform(lambda s: s.expanding(3).mean()).iloc[1179:]
df1['Away score'] = df.groupby(['Away team'])['Away score']\
                      .transform(lambda s: s.expanding(3).mean()).iloc[1179:]
```

Basically we use from the original dataframe and:

- group per team to get only results of that team
- `.transform` to return a series with the same index, basically do not change the shape of what is returned
- inside the transform we now have only the games we want to average, so we run an expanding mean with a minimum of 3 values
- finally we limit what we put into `df1` by cutting the results off before row 1179